# Unable to import user services in to report controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

Hi I'm working on a nest Js mini project,
I have two separate modules called reports and users.
Both of them have their own Service, controller and repositories.

reports have many to one relation with users.

I wanted to add user property to the reports.

I'm trying to import service class of users in reports controller.
Please find the code below:

users.service.ts

```
    import { BadRequestException, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from './users.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Users) private userRepository: Repository<Users>
    ) {
        userRepository.remove = userRepository.softRemove;
        userRepository.delete = userRepository.softDelete;
    }
    createUser(body: object) {
        const instance = this.userRepository.create(body);
        return this.userRepository.save(instance);
    }

    find(query: object) {
        return this.userRepository.find({ "where": query })
    }

    findOne(id: any) {
        if (!id) {
            throw new BadRequestException('Id not found')
        }
        return this.userRepository.findOne({ "where": { "id": id } });
    }

    async update(id: string, record: Partial<Users>) {
        var user = await this.findOne(id);
        if (!user) {
            return new NotFoundException('User Not Found');
        }
        return this.userRepository.save(Object.assign(user, record));
    }

    async delete(id: string) {
        var user = await this.findOne(id);
        if (!user || user === null) {
            throw new NotFoundException('User Not Found');
        }
        else {
            this.userRepository.remove(user)
            return "Successfully deleted"
        }
    }
}
```

reports.controller.ts

```
import { Body, ClassSerializerInterceptor, Controller, Post, Session, UseGuards, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service';
import { ReportsService } from './reports.service';

@Controller('reports')
export class ReportsController {
    constructor(
        private reportsService: ReportsService,
        private usersService:UsersService
    ) { }
}
```

But I'm getting some error.
Please see the screenshot also
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFALh.png)

I'm stuck here from long time, Please help me to resolve this.
Please find more code files on my github : https://github.com/Rakshith083/NestJs-Car-Pricing/tree/master/src

Comment: What does your users service look like?

Comment: Hi @vr I have added users.services.ts code for you, Please have a look

Comment: I think you have to add the UsersService to your module.

Comment: Can you show your `ReportsModule` and your `UsersModule`?

Comment: Hi,
Please find more code on my github https://github.com/Rakshith083/NestJs-Car-Pricing/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with modules and sharing services, the service's originating module, where it is first registered, should have the service in both the `providers` and `exports` array, so that the service is registered to the DI container and made available to other modules. Then, when that service needs to be used in a service of a different module, the service's originating module should be added to the new service's originating module's `imports` array. In your case, the `UsersModule` should add `UsersService` to the `exports` array, and `ReportsModule` should add `UsersModule` to the `imports` array.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { Users } from './users.entity';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/auth.service';

@Module({
  imports:[TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Users])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService,AuthService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { ReportsController } from './reports.controller';
import { Reports } from './reports.entity';
import { ReportsService } from './reports.service';

@Module({
  imports:[TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Reports]), UsersModule],
  controllers: [ReportsController],
  providers: [ReportsService]
})
export class ReportsModule {}
```

You probably should also look at fixing the `AuthService` to come from the `AuthModule` instead of re-creating the `AuthService`, but that's just some friendly advice

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable  information.
Thanks a lot for resolving my issue.